# JavaScript two objects - overriding each other

Tags: javascript, prototype, javascript-objects

I am trying to learn Object Oriented Programming in JavaScript. Therefore, I may be wrong in what I am doing.

I have one JS function (class):

```
function User() {
    //initiating object code goes here
}

//Functions
User.prototype.getEmpId = function() {
    return this.empId;
}

var myUser = new User({'empid':'1'});

console.log(myUser.getEmpId()); //Returns 1

var mynewuser = new User({'empid':'2'});

console.log(myUser.getEmpId()); //Returns 2

console.log(mynewuser.getEmpId()); //Returns 2
```

I don't understand what is going wrong here. If these two are two different objects then why is it causing problem. I have added the complete code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/srivastaveer/dg1negkb/1/).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Would you like to check this.. http://jsfiddle.net/c5yhpav9/2/

Comment: Not working.. check my code. It is not huge as it appears to be

Comment: Aah..I know where are you making a mistake..Actually you are not at all setting properties on instances of `User` itself..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

User.prototype.getEmpId gets overridden each time you instantiate the User object. The prototype property is shared between all instances.

Then what to do:

```
User.prototype.getEmpId = function() {
  return this.empId;
}
```

Comment: Yes, but the empId property belongs to the instance itself, not to its prototype. The getEmpId() is just a function returning that value.

Comment: Then what to do in this case.?

Answer (score 3):

```
User.prototype.getEmpId() {
  return this.empId;
}
```

should be

```
User.prototype.getEmpId = function () {
  return this.empId;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Check this fiddle :

http://jsfiddle.net/c5yhpav9/2/

```
function User(obj) {
//initiating object code goes here
this.empId=obj.empid;
}

//getEmpId now shared for all the instances of User
User.prototype.getEmpId=function() {
   return this.empId;
}

var myUser = new User({'empid':'1'});

alert(myUser.getEmpId()); //Returns 1

var mynewuser = new User({'empid':'2'});

alert(myUser.getEmpId()); //Returns 1

alert(mynewuser.getEmpId()); //Returns 2
```

Now gettting back to the problem you are facing in your sample shared. I found that you are setting properties/values on the `User.prototype` object itself each time a `User` object is instantiated. Rather, you should set on each `instances` of `User`. Following is the updated jsfiddle which works:

http://jsfiddle.net/L3qs4eg7/

Major Changes done:

first,

```
formUserObjectFromObject.call(this);//calling with reference of this
```

and,

```
function formUserObjectFromObject() {
    //Will only be called for one object.
    for (var userKey in arg[0]) {
        switch(userKey) {
            case "appId": 
                //Calling setAppId on this to set value of property
                this.setAppId(arg[0][userKey]);
                break;
            case "empId":
                this.setEmpId(arg[0][userKey]);
                break;
            case "firstName":
                this.setFirstName(arg[0][userKey]);
                break;
            case "lastName":
                this.setLastName(arg[0][userKey]);
                break;
            case "roleId":
                this.setRoleId(arg[0][userKey]);
                break;
            case "emailId":
                this.setEmailId(arg[0][userKey]);
                break;
            case "supervisorId":
                this.setSupervisorId(arg[0][userKey]);
                break;
            default:
                this.setCustom(userKey, arg[0][userKey]);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Hope that helps to understand!